# Issues with some products when I try to duplicate

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, duplicate

I'm having problems in duplicating of 4 products. I don't have problem with the other products in the catalog, curiously belongs to the "mug" category.
I checked the functions, the database and their relations and constraints, but I don't understand the reason.

Comment: what issues or error you are facing at the time of duplicating ?

Comment: when I click the button "duplictate" I recieve this message : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myparty1_magento3`.`catalog_product_link`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNKED_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`linked_product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link` (`product_id`, `linked_product_id`, `link_type_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)

Comment: why dont you create those 4 products manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was because one of the listed **cross sells** or **up-sells** has been deleted. Layer 8 problem. cofcofcofUserscofcofcof  Thanks  Everyone.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73774)

Comment: I'm newbee here, so.. I'm not sure how those forums works. Thanks.